# Rails: How do I add a "remove item" to carts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm unsure how I could implement this feature because as of now, if a user adds an item to a cart, it stays there and they are unable to remove the item from the cart.

Comment: You need to create `destroy` method in `cart_items_controller.rb` and in `cart_item.rb` model, write `after_destroy callback` which will calculate the cart total cost and save cart with latest detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a method remove_item:

```
def remove_item product_id, cart_items
  cart_items.delete(product_id)
end
```

Call this method to remove items in your cart as:

```
@cart.remove_item params[:id], session[:cart_item]
```

Comment: I put it in `Cart.rb` using `<%= @cart.remove_item params[:id] %>` and I got error `undefined local variable or method session' for #<Cart not initialized>`

Comment: No luck, I got the error `undefined method delete' for nil:NilClass` :(